# counting cells with font colors in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, counting

I need to count the number of color font occurance in a column?
In 'my column' you can see that I have used bullets and coloured them differently.
For now, I am sorting the cells by font colors and calculate the number of each color occurence manually, however, the range is very vast and I'd like to do it by using some formula.

[image: my column]

Could you help me?

Comment: How are you sorting the cells by font colors? do you mean by number of font colors?

Comment: No, just by using data filtering and in the options you can find filter by font color. When I'm choosing e.g. blue, it outputs all cells with that blue color, no matter whether there are any other colors. So in my pic, it would give both 2nd and 6th cell.

I would like the formula to show that, yes, the blue color was found twice.
I am not sure if it is possible...

Comment: You could write a User-Defined Function (UDF) in VBA but that would require the user to enable macro... so only with default formula looking at font color is not possible. Do you want the UDF still?

Comment: Do you use text to create the bullets, or do you use the drawing tools to draw a circle?

Comment: @kpark91 - UDF too advanced, but thank you :)

Comment: @Sean Cheshire - I've used bullets as text

Comment: as @kpark91 said, without using VBA, it's impossible. [CPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/colors.aspx) has a section on using VBA and colors

Answer (score 0):

`only with default formula looking at font color is not possible` per kpark.

`without using VBA, it's impossible` per Sean Cheshire.